# How to explain the process of image formation with the help of wavefronts (Huygen's principle)?

Tags: optics, wave-particle-duality

[image]

For example, in this picture, how do we show that the image A'B' will be shorter than the real object AB? (In case of the plano-convex lens placed between the object AB and the screen S such that conditions for the formation of a real image on the screen S is fulfilled.